# What is this Vim sequence 09. doing?

Tags: vim

There's a Vimgolf exercise to convert this:

```
- One number per line -
-----------------------
2,3,5,7,
11,13,17,
19,23,29,
```

To this using Vim:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

One possible solution is:

```
dj3JAwr<CR><Esc>ux09@.ZZ
```

My question is - what does the "09@." part of the command do?  I understand 0 is the beginning of a sentence, 9 is the end, and "." means repeat command.

But what command is being repeated?  And do "09@." mean something different when strung together in sequence?

Answer (score 2):

`09@.`  is:

- `0`: **go** to **first character** of the **line**.
- `9@.`: **execute** the **content** of **register** `.` **9** times.

The register `.` is defined as:

> ```
>                                         quote_. quote. E29
> ".      Contains the last inserted text (the same as what is inserted
>         with the insert mode commands CTRL-A and CTRL-@). (...)
> ```

You can still check its content by executing:

```
:register .
```

which gives `wr^@`  So vim here is changing the newline into a null character and do not give what you expect.

So `dj3JAwr<CR><Esc>ux09@.ZZ` can never be a solution for the problem especially as `J` leave also a space when joining lines.